# CEF + VUEJS performance issue on listening mouse click event after 4-5 times render

Tags: vue.js, chromium-embedded

I'm trying to use CEF + VUEJS in my game

I have component "item"
If I'm using v-on:click="onMouseDown" then after 4-5 renderings of the item listening of this event will be happen only after 10-12 seconds after mounted.

```js
<template>
    <div class="item" v-on:click="onMouseDown">
        <good />
    </div>
</template>
...
methods: {
            onMouseDown: function (e) {
                if (this.$parent.writeonly) {
                    return;
                }
                if (this.$parent.$parent.floatItem) {
                    this.$parent.$parent.floatItem = undefined;
                } else {
                    this.$parent.$parent.floatItem = this.data;
                    this.$parent.$parent.boardBackIndex = this.$parent.boardIndex;
                    this.$parent.$parent.boardBack = this.$parent.listname;
                    this.$parent.globalData[this.$parent.listname].is[this.$parent.boardIndex].i = undefined;
                    this.$parent.$parent.clientX = e.clientX;
                    this.$parent.$parent.clientY = e.clientY;
                }
            }
        },
```

With this workaround everything works ok.

```js
        mounted: function () {
            this.$el.addEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, false);
        },
        beforeDestroy: function () {
            this.$el.removeEventListener('mousedown', this.onMouseDown, false);
        },
```

With regular 80 chrome there is no such issue.

I have tried to logging mouse injection everything is ok. So really component will start listening this event only after 10-12 seconds on 4th-5th time rendering.

Please help me

Comment: I have checked in dev tools of CEF and there is no blocked threads or processes with such long response time

Comment: What version of `CEF` are you using? Generally speaking https://magpcss.org/ceforum/index.php is a better place to get help for anything `CEF` related.

Comment: "cef_binary_76.1.13+gf19c584+chromium-76.0.3809.132_windows32"

Comment: Try a support version see https://bitbucket.org/chromiumembedded/cef/wiki/BranchesAndBuilding.md#markdown-header-current-release-branches-supported

Comment: Compiling CEF spents almost 48 hours. Are you sure that this is an issue of CEF and it was fixed?

Comment: Builds are available from http://opensource.spotify.com/cefbuilds/index.html including a sample application for testing purposes. You will need to test with a supported version. Unsupported really does mean unsupported in this case.